# How can I reference ProcessInfo's members and ProcessCE in my Windows CE util?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, kill, kill-process

I found this code from CathalMF [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307998/how-to-kill-process-in-windows-ce):

```
ProcessInfo[] list = ProcessCE.GetProcesses();

foreach (ProcessInfo pinfo in list)
{
    if (pinfo.FullPath.EndsWith("MyExe.exe"))
        pinfo.Kill();
}
```

...and modified it to my ends (no pun intended) like so:

```
ProcessInfo[] list = ProcessCE.GetProcesses();

foreach (ProcessInfo pinfo in list)
{
    if (pinfo.FullPath.EndsWith("HHS.exe"))
        pinfo.Kill();
    // This should work, too, eh?
    if (pinfo.FullPath.EndsWith("HUtilCE.dll"))
        pinfo.Kill();
}
```

...but several things are unresolvable in that code (ProcessInfo's FullPath property and Kill method, and ProcessCE). What assembl[ies,y] need I reference to get this to compile?

I added System.Web, which made ProcessInfo itself resolvable, but that is not enough. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.71).aspx) indicates that I need System.Diagnostics.Process, but I don't have that on my system...???

This is a small VS 2008 util targeting the Windows CE platform.

### UPDATE

Apparently (although a hard-drive search for "System.Diagnostics.Process.dll" turned up nothing), adding the following usings did the trick:

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

I added these usings in conjunction with this code I got from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36841/Compact-Framework-Process-class-that-supports-full):

```
ProcessInfo[] list = ProcessCE.GetProcesses();

foreach (ProcessInfo item in list)
{
    //Debug.WriteLine("Process item: " + item.FullPath);
    MessageBox.Show("Process item: " + item.FullPath);
    if (item.FullPath.EndsWith("HHS.exe"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("about to kill hhs.exe");
        item.Kill();
    }
    if (item.FullPath.EndsWith("HUtilCE.dll"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("about to kill hutilce.dll");
        item.Kill();
    }
}
```

Did the simple act of running that code cause the resident-in-memory binaries to be freed? I don't know, but being a little bit (albeit not super)-stitious, I'll run this code again if I ever run into the same problem again.

Note, though, that it never showed me my .exe or .dll in the list of running processes. All I saw were:

```
nk.exe
shell.exe
udevice.exe <= 5 times!
RTLogExport.exe
explorer.exe
servicesd.exe
WCLaunch.exe <= this explains a lot -- somebody is apparently launching a water closet on the device
keyicons.exe
repllog.exe
rapisrv.exe
rnaapp.exe
udp2ftp.exe
cerdisp.exe
PrinterCommanderCE.exe <= this is my util that was running this code
```

Is it a problem that there were five instances of udevice?

Why did running this solve my problem (if, indeed, that was the solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class (ProcessInfo) you are using is not the one defined in the System.Web, it's completely different class. Check out the code from this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36841/Compact-Framework-Process-class-that-supports-full), it has ProcessCE and ProcessInfo classes defined, you'll need both.